# how to call asp.net mvc 4 rest method from java code

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, rest

i have this order controller and the method below.
how can i call this method from java?
the link is also available online under: http://www.life-projects.com/api/orders

```
public class OrdersController : ApiController
{

    [HttpPost]
    public String Add(String order)
    {
        return "test string";
    }
}
```

this is the code that tries to access the method

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.life-projects.com/api/orders");

httppost.setEntity(new StringEntity(Order_Data));    
HttpResponse resp = httpclient.execute(httppost);

HttpEntity ent = resp.getEntity();
```

someone tries to call the post method and it doesn't work.

why?

thanks,

Comment: You need to provide code that you use to "tries to call post method". There should be absolutely nothing specific to ASP.Net/MVC - likely your Java code is not doing right thing. (or JavaScript?)

Comment: i get this error:
<Error><Message>No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://www.life-projects.com/api/orders'.</Message><MessageDetail>No action was found on the controller 'Orders' that matches the request.</MessageDetail></Error

Comment: Please Post the code you are using to make the request.

Comment: The url only reaches to controller level, have you defined in your routing that default action is "Add"? Otherwise you need to change your url to *"http://www.life-projects.com/api/orders/add"* in order to reach the action